# How to bind a datasource to a dropdown in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps

How do you bind a datasource to a dropdown in PowerApps.

I have connected my Azure table to my PowerApps app so that the tables appear in my Data Sources.

I then added a dropdown control to my form.

In my Items property I can have list values  hardcoded e.g.

`Table({ColorName:"red"; ID: "1"};{ColorName:"green"; ID: "2"}{ColorName:"blue"; ID: "3"})`

but I want to link it to my DataSourceTable values that has `"ID"` and `"ColorName"` columns.

According to this [help page](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/control-drop-down/) I just need to put my tablename in the Items Property but this doesn't work.

Comment: For me better answer in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490200/how-to-set-the-default-value-of-a-dropdown-in-powerapps  Here how applied: [how to bind DropDownList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9zoV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to put the table name as it appears under data sources in single quotations

`'[dbo].[MyTableName]'`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Dropdown1.Items = Distinct(DataSource, ID) for ID Dropdown
```

or

```
Dropdown1.Items = Distinct(DataSource, ColorName) for ColorName Dropdown.
```

Hope this helps.