# How to set the default value of a dropdown in powerapps

Tags: powerapps

I have a dropdown in powerapps and need to set the default value

My `Items` property of my dropdown I have it linked to my data source which is an Azure table.

`'[dbo].[ColorTable]'`

One could see the contents simplified as the following

`Table({ColorName:"red"; ID: "1"};{ColorName:"green"; ID: "2"}{ColorName:"blue"; ID: "3"})`

although I have many more entries.

In my details edit screen I have the ID value in my main datasource. However I need to set the dropdown's default with this value, however the dropdown use the `ColorName` as it's value.

How do I set the dropdowns default `ID` value since its Value is `ColorName` and not `ID`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a workaround that works but in conjunction with saving the selected value back again it can conflict with the saving.

In the `Default` property of the dropdown I add the following code

```
LookUp('[dbo].[ColorTable]';ID=ThisItem.fk_ColorID;ColorName)
```

Comment: What is the conflict that you have when saving the value?

Comment: This doesn't currently work, at least not when using SharePoint lists as the data source.  No error message, but nothing is selected in the combobox.

Comment: It won't work if data is static e.g. ["A","B","C","D"]